# How to use Angular FormBuilder with Angular Material mat-datapicker

Tags: angular, mat

I am currently attempting to use [`mat-datepicker`](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview), with the Angular Form Builder. The only issue, is that mat-datepicker will return the selected value as a `Date` object instead of a string. This does not allow for the value to be immediately passed in from the mat-datepicker into a formGroup, and then sent as a request to the server without first converting it to a string.

In addition, using the material date picker offers various ways of changing values [parsed and formatted](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats), however, it is still the date object that is returned. The [following is a stackblitz](https://angular-material-nw1brd.stackblitz.io), which proves that the mat-datepicker returns an object, instead of the expected string. You will have to open up console in order to see value.

If you have any recommendations on how I can provide a value from a module side of things, so that `mat-datepicker` returns a string instead of a date object, it would be very much so appreciated. Thank you.

*I have also submitted a feature request here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16010*

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a string with a function (*typecript*):

```
    /**
     * Convert date to string with 'dd/MM/yyyy' format
     *
     * @param date: Date
     */
    dateFormat(date: Date): string {
        const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        const day = date.getDate();
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        if (date) {
            return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
        }

        return '';
    }
```

Ex:

```
   let date = Wed May 15 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)
   console.log('Convert Date : ', dateFormat(date));
   Result: 15/05/2019
```

Comment: If you could elaborate, that would be fantastic. Is this by using a data adapter as a provider, or a general function? If it is a general function that is plan B, but ideally this should be something offered as a provider to the module.

Comment: This is a general function.
The NativeDateAdapter doesn't support DD/MM/YYYY so you'll need to use the MomentDateAdapter or a custom one. [more detail](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)

Comment: Tan, I actually think that using an adapter might not work(MomentDateAdapter). What you are suggesting is using a general function within the component. What I am asking is a way so that there is no general function need within the component.

Comment: Can't. https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-selected-date